# Hover button state on touchable area (iPad)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, touch

I'd like to find the general solution for hovering effect on buttons like native iOS and browser buttons when button changing view if I press it. In my case the buttons are  or  tags. When I press button it should be changed to pressed button state. Also if I touched screen  outside of the button and move finger into button the button's state should be changed to pressed. And vise versa.
Any solutions or hints?

Answer (score 0):

since touch gadgets have no hover effect because of absence of cursor.
So you have to use

```
button{background:#fff;}
button:active{background:#ccc;}
```

and for `if I touched screen outside of the button and move finger into button the button's state should be changed to pressed.` you will need some client-side script.